# How to set a global vim 'project root' path

Tags: vim, path, project

When I'm working in vim, I usually have multiple buffers on screen at once and need to switch between them and open new files a lot. I've installed the Command-T plugin to facilitate fast file switching but I'm having a few issues with it.

Whenever I press Command-T, it only shows files in the same folder (and sub folders) of the file I am currently editing.

I want it to show me all of the files in my project i.e.:

```
Project Folder:
~/project1/

Current Buffer:
~/project1/front/js/file1.js
```

When I press Command+T in the buffer, I want it to display files starting from the project folder.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any sign that can be used to identify the main project directory? Like a certain pattern in the directory name, or a file/directory that only exists in the main directory of each project?

Comment: No, But I could make a change so that there is eg. a file called project in the root.

I guess this could be used in a recursive search?

Comment: Possibly the [harpoon plugin](https://github.com/ThePrimeagen/harpoon) fits your needs of switching files within projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is because CommandT searches in present working directory. You can see what your working directory is with the `:pwd` command.  When you open a file with the gui it sets your present working directory to the directory that file contains. As romainl said you can simply `:cd` into your project's root directory and then CommandT will search from there (remember to `:CommandTFlush`)

Alternatively you could use [ctrl-p](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) (which I personally prefer since it doesn't require compiling a C helper program). It has an option `ctrlp_working_path_mode` option changes the working directory to the first ancestor that contains one of the following directories or files:

```
.git/
.hg/
.bzr/
_darcs/
root.dir
.vimprojects
```

Answer (score 4):

Put the following function in your `.vimrc`:

```
function! FindProjectRoot(lookFor)
    let pathMaker='%:p'
    while(len(expand(pathMaker))>1)
        let pathMaker=pathMaker.':h'
        let fileToCheck=expand(pathMaker).'/'.a:lookFor
        if filereadable(fileToCheck)||isdirectory(fileToCheck)
            return expand(pathMaker)
        endif
    endwhile
    return 0
endfunction
```

That function will search upward from to current file for a parent folder that contains a file or folder with the specified name, and returns that path. That way, you can put a `project` file in the project's root folder, and send `FindProjectRoot('project')` as an argument to Command-T

Or even better - call that file `project.vim`, and use it to load specific settings and keybindings for each project.

***EDIT***
that function will only work on linux. Use this function instead:

```
function! FindProjectRoot(lookFor)
    let pathMaker='%:p'
    while(len(expand(pathMaker))>len(expand(pathMaker.':h')))
        let pathMaker=pathMaker.':h'
        let fileToCheck=expand(pathMaker).'/'.a:lookFor
        if filereadable(fileToCheck)||isdirectory(fileToCheck)
            return expand(pathMaker)
        endif
    endwhile
    return 0
endfunction
```

Comment: Hi Idan, This looks like the sort of thing I want - I can use it in conjunction with @David Brown's answer to find the project root.

Answer (score 3):

`:help command-t-usage` recommends to `:cd` into your project folder before using it.

You can also pass it a path as argument as in

```
:CommandT ..
```

Comment: Hi, I understand that; just seems like a lot of hassle when trying to quickly open files.

Comment: There are a few nice answers in this thread. I agree with you, the default way seems like a hassle but you can do something like `nnoremap <leader>tt :CommandT ..<CR>` to make the whole thing easier.

Comment: On a side note, I find that using tags and `gf` are enough to satisfy most of my in-project navigational needs.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer: I wrote the following plugin**

I would suggest to use [codepath.vim](https://github.com/lucapette/codepath.vim) if you are used to store all your code in the same dir. So, you could do the following:

```
map <silent> <C-T> :CommandT <c-r>=codepath#path()<CR><CR>
imap <silent> <C-T> <ESC>:CommandT <c-r>=codepath#path()<CR><CR>
```

And CommandT will open itself in the root dir of your project.

Comment: it's very useful, it was case

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the Command-T plugin, but you could try `set path=<project_path>` to set Vim's search path for files.

If not, setting `:cd <path>` would probably work, but that's rather a drastic solution!